# Retornar todos os aniversariantes do mês escolhido pelo usuário

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de uma agenda de amigos.
Algumas classes foram criadas: `Endereço`, `Amigo`, `GerenciarAmigo`.

Quando coloco o sistema para rodar, o mesmo não me mostra a `String` dos nomes de aniversariantes daquele mês, mas sim apenas uma pessoa.

O método que fiz foi este:

```
//Metodo que recebe um mês e retorna todos os amigos aniversariantes

public static String aniversariarNoMes(int mes) {
    String saida = "";

    //Faz a validação do mes escolhido
    if (mes < 01 || mes > 12) {
        return "Mês invalido.";
    } else {
        //Percorre o ArrayList a procura do mes informado
        for (Amigo amigo : agenda) {
            if (mes == amigo.getMesNas()) {
                saida = amigo.getNome() + "\n";

                return saida; //retorna os nomes encontrados
            }

            return saida+=amigo.getNome()+"\n";
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, quando for colar código no StackOverflow, insira 4 caracteres antes de cada linha de código. Desta forma, o código fica legível.

Comment: Sou novo por aqui, logo não conheço muito bem. Mas irei me atentar, obrigado.

Comment: Mas se o mês de nascimento de `amigo` for o desejado, você atualiza o valor de `saida` e imediatamente o retorna, saindo do método. O correto não seria apenas concatenar o valor e apenas no final retornar? Aliás, se é novo na comunidade, comece fazendo o [tour].

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss O correto é que eu sou novo em programação e estou buscando ajuda. Este foi o motivo de ter entrado na comunidade.

Comment: E estamos aqui para ajudar. Já fez o teste de mesa para entender o que o seu código faz?

Comment: Fiz não @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Se tiver usando Calendar para pegar o mes, ele não conta de 1 a 12 e sim de 0 a 11. No mais, seu código está confuso, faltam coisas ai para que se compreenda melhor, como essa classe Amigo e como você chama este método.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss posso postar todo o código?

Comment: Eu não acho estritatemente necessário, pois o erro de lógica é claro já no código postado. Se fizer o teste de mesa, talvez fique claro para você também. Sabe fazer? Agora, aqui temos excelentes programadores Java. Talvez se postar o código completo, poderá ter dicas de melhores implementações se for o caso.

Comment: Como faz o teste de mesa?

Answer (score 3):

Consideremos que você possui a seguinte lista de amigos:

```
Amigo[] agenda = {
    new Amigo("João", "20/01/1983"),
    new Amigo("Marcia", "12/08/1990"),
    new Amigo("Lucas", "02/12/1989"),
    new Amigo("Tereza", "30/08/1985")
}
```

Você deseja obter a lista de aniversariantes do mês 08, então chama o método:

```
String aniversariantes = objeto.aniversariarNoMes(8);
```

Considerando a implementação inicial do método:

```
public static String aniversariarNoMes(int mes) {
    String saida = "";

    if (mes < 01 || mes > 12) {
        return "Mês invalido.";
    } else {
        for (Amigo amigo : agenda) {
            if (mes == amigo.getMesNas()) {
                saida = amigo.getNome() + "\n";

                return saida;
            }

            return saida+=amigo.getNome()+"\n";
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Siga os passos que serão executados (teste de mesa):

1. O método `aniversariarNoMes` é chamado com o valor `mes = 8`;
2. É definido uma *string* `saida` vazia;
3. Verifica se o mês informado é válido (entre 1 e 12, inclusive);
4. O valor é válido, então é executado o `else`;
5. Percorre a lista de amigos definida em `agenda`;

   1. O valor de `amigo` será `Amigo("João", "20/01/1983")`;
   2. Verifica se o mês de aniversário de `amigo` é 8;
   3. Falso, não é executado o `if`;
   4. Retorna o valor de `saida`, concatenado com o nome de `amigo`;

Como foi retornado, o método é finalizado e, portanto, o valor retornado seria `João\n`. Além de ter retornado antes da hora, retornou um valor inesperado, visto que João faz aniversário no mês 01. Com isso você já sabe que este `return` não faz sentido ficar aí. Removendo-o, fica:

```
public static String aniversariarNoMes(int mes) {
    String saida = "";

    if (mes < 01 || mes > 12) {
        return "Mês invalido.";
    } else {
        for (Amigo amigo : agenda) {
            if (mes == amigo.getMesNas()) {
                saida = amigo.getNome() + "\n";

                return saida;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Refazendo o teste de mesa:

1. O método `aniversariarNoMes` é chamado com o valor `mes = 8`;
2. É definido uma *string* `saida` vazia;
3. Verifica se o mês informado é válido (entre 1 e 12, inclusive);
4. O valor é válido, então é executado o `else`;
5. Percorre a lista de amigos definida em `agenda`;

   1. O valor de `amigo` será `Amigo("João", "20/01/1983")`;
   2. Verifica se o mês de aniversário de `amigo` é 8;
   3. Falso, não é executado o `if`;
   4. Na próxima iteração do `for`, `amigo` vale `Amigo("Marcia", "12/08/1990")`;
   5. Verifica se o mês de aniversário de `amigo` é 8;
   6. Verdadeiro, então é executado o `if`;
   7. Atualiza o valor de `saida` para o nome de `amigo`;
   8. Retorna o valor de `amigo`;

Como retornou, novamente o método é finalizado. Neste caso, o retorno seria `Marcia\n`. De fato este registro faz aniversário no mês 8, mas não é o único, então não podemos finalizar o método nesta hora. Isso nos mostra que novamente este `return` está errado. Removendo-o, fica:

```
public static String aniversariarNoMes(int mes) {
    String saida = "";

    if (mes < 01 || mes > 12) {
        return "Mês invalido.";
    } else {
        for (Amigo amigo : agenda) {
            if (mes == amigo.getMesNas()) {
                saida = amigo.getNome() + "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Refazendo o teste de mesa:

1. O método `aniversariarNoMes` é chamado com o valor `mes = 8`;
2. É definido uma *string* `saida` vazia;
3. Verifica se o mês informado é válido (entre 1 e 12, inclusive);
4. O valor é válido, então é executado o `else`;
5. Percorre a lista de amigos definida em `agenda`;

   1. O valor de `amigo` será `Amigo("João", "20/01/1983")`;
   2. Verifica se o mês de aniversário de `amigo` é 8;
   3. Falso, não é executado o `if`;
   4. Na próxima iteração do `for`, `amigo` vale `Amigo("Marcia", "12/08/1990")`;
   5. Verifica se o mês de aniversário de `amigo` é 8;
   6. Verdadeiro, então é executado o `if`;
   7. Atualiza o valor de `saida` para o nome de `amigo`;
   8. Na próxima iteração do `for`, `amigo` vale `Amigo("Lucas", "02/12/1989")`;
   9. Verifica se o mês de aniversário de `amigo` é 8;
   10. Falso, não é executado o `if`;
   11. Na próxima iteração do `for`, `amigo` vale `Amigo("Tereza", "30/08/1985")`;
   12. Verifica se o mês de aniversário de `amigo` é 8;
   13. Verdadeiro, então é executado o `if`;
   14. Atualiza o valor de `saida` para o nome de `amigo`;
6. A lista é finalizada, então encerra-se o `for`;
7. Retorna `null`;

Já percebemos que agora está sempre retornando `null`, então deve haver outro `return` no código que nos retorne o valor correto. Como já vimos que dentro do `for` não funciona, basta colocarmos fora do mesmo:

```
public static String aniversariarNoMes(int mes) {
    String saida = "";

    if (mes < 01 || mes > 12) {
        return "Mês invalido.";
    } else {
        for (Amigo amigo : agenda) {
            if (mes == amigo.getMesNas()) {
                saida = amigo.getNome() + "\n";
            }
        }

        return saida;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Mas se você analisar o item 5.14 do último teste de mesa, verá que o valor de `saida` termina valendo `Tereza\n`. Não é isso que queremos, mas sim a lista de nomes dos aniversariantes. Ou seja, dentro do `if`, não podemos apenas fazer a atribuição simples ao valor de `saida`, mas sim concatenar ao valor atual. Para fazer isso:

```
public static String aniversariarNoMes(int mes) {
    String saida = "";

    if (mes < 01 || mes > 12) {
        return "Mês invalido.";
    } else {
        for (Amigo amigo : agenda) {
            if (mes == amigo.getMesNas()) {
                saida += amigo.getNome() + "\n";
            }
        }

        return saida;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Desta forma, o código deve retornar `Marcia\nTereza\n`, que é o esperado, ou `null` se não houverem aniversariantes. Deixo o teste de mesa desta versão como atividade para você. Faça-o e veja se realmente condiz com que o código faz.

Answer (score 0):

//Metodo que recebe um mês e retorna todos os amigos aniversariantes

```
public static String aniversariarNoMes(int mes) {
    String saida = "";
    //Faz a validação do mes escolhido
    if (mes < 01 || mes > 12) {
        return "Mês invalido.";
    } else {
        //Percorre o ArrayList a procura do mes informado
        for (Amigo amigo : agenda) {
            if (mes == amigo.getMesNas()) {
                saida += amigo.getNome() + "\n";

            }

        }
        return saida;
    }



}
```

Comment: Este você já postou na pergunta. Ah, este campo é para repostas. Se for atualizar a pergunta com a classe Amigo e como você chama este método, edite pergunta.

Comment: Esse código parece fazer sentido agora. Você está postando-o como solução? Se sim, por favor, descreva com palavras o que estava errado e aquilo que fez para resolver. Se for apenas informações extras sobre a pergunta, não utilize esta área e sim, faça a edição diretamente na pergunta. Reforço a dica de fazer o [tour] para entender como a comunidade funciona.

Comment: Dei uma editada no código.

Comment: Esse código funcionou?

Comment: Sim. Fiz um comentário sobre este novo código, mas não sei onde foi parar.